# why do i have to specify "use feature :5.1x" even when my installed perl is 5.14?

Tags: perl

I have 5.14.2 installed in my machine but when i try to execute a print statement with `say` keyword it gives me error.

I have go with the use keyword to make the program run without error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature ':5.10';
say "hello";
```

5.14.2 is latest when compared to 5.010 so it should have all those features enabled by default right ? then what is the point in specifying the version using `use` keyword ?

Answer (score 10):

Perl attempts to maintain backward compatibility.  It's quite possible that existing scripts might have subroutines named `say`.  There is considerable on-going discussion of whether or not some future version of Perl should stop these efforts and streamline its internals. See, for instance, [naming and numbering perl](http://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/1989) .

Answer (score 5):

It prevents conflicts with existing programs written in Perl.

For example, say I wrote a program for Perl 5.6 which defined a subroutine called `say`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub say { print 1; }
say();
```

That works fine (outputting *1*), and it still works in perls that include the `say` feature.

Now let's enable the native `say` and see what happens:

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub say { print 1; }
say();
```

Now it falls over with *Use of uninitialized value $_ in say at - line 5.*

You need to `use feature` or `use v5.xx` so that the new features can be loaded safely, i.e. when the author knows he wants to use them.

Comment: does that mean irrespective of any latest version of perl,  its all going to function in one common way unless you specify which version to use. and once you specify the version it is going to enable those features for you.
So does that mean my 5.8 and 5.10 versions is going to be the same without `use`command feature

Comment: That is the basic idea, yes. However, use feature or version is only for enabling NEW features. Bugs or mis-features are sometimes removed with a deprecation cycle.  So, what was a warning in 5.8 might be a failure in 5.10.